# columnSummary is not added

Tags: vue.js, handsontable

I am trying to add columnSummary to my table using Handsontable. But it seems that the function does not fire. The stretchH value gets set and is set properly. But it does not react to the columnSummary option:

```
this.$refs.hot.hotInstance.updateSettings({stretchH: 'all',columnSummary: [
        {
           destinationRow: 0,
           destinationColumn: 2,
           reversedRowCoords: true,
           type: 'custom',
           customFunction: function(endpoint) {
            console.log("TEST");
           }
       }]
 }, false);
```

I have also tried with `type:'sum'` without any luck.

Thanks for all help and guidance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`columnSummary` cannot be changed with `updateSettings`: [GH #3597](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/3597)

You can set `columnSummary` settings at the initialization of Handsontable.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround would be to somehow manage your own column summary, since Handsontable one could give you some headeache. So you may try to [add one additional row to put your arithmetic](https://forum.handsontable.com/t/gh-3597-column-summary-not-getting-reapplied-after-the-data-of-the-table-is-changed-angular/2536/9) in, but it is messy (it needs fixed rows number and does not work with filtering and sorting operations. Still, it could work well under some circumstances.

In my humble opinion though, a summary column has to be fully functionnal. We then need to set our summary row out of the table data. What comes to mind is to take the above mentioned additional row and take it away from the table data "area" but it would force us to make that *out of the table row* always looks like it still was in the table.

So I thought that instead of having a new line we could just have to add our column summary within column header:
[image]

Here is a [working JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/s_2_h/3597z42u/).

Once the Handsontable table is rendered, we need to iterate through the columns and set our column summary right in the table cell HTML content:

```
for(var i=0;i<tableConfig.columns.length;i++) {
    var columnHeader = document.querySelectorAll('.ht_clone_top th')[i];
    if(columnHeader) { // Just to be sure column header exists
        var summaryColumnHeader = document.createElement('div');
        summaryColumnHeader.className = 'custom-column-summary';
        columnHeader.appendChild( summaryColumnHeader );
    }
}
```

Now that our placeholders are set, we have to update them with some arithmetic results:

```
var printedData = hotInstance.getData();
for(var i=0;i<tableConfig.columns.length;i++) {
    var summaryColumnHeader = document.querySelectorAll('.ht_clone_top th')[i].querySelector('.custom-column-summary'); // Get back our column summary for each column
    if(summaryColumnHeader) {
        var res = 0;
        printedData.forEach(function(row) { res += row[i] }); // Count all data that are stored under that column
        summaryColumnHeader.innerText = '= '+ res;
    }
}
```

This piece of code function may be called anytime it should be:

```
var hotInstance = new Handsontable(/* ... */);
setMySummaryHeaderCalc(); // When Handsontable table is printed
Handsontable.hooks.add('afterFilter', function(conditionsStack) { // When Handsontable table is filtered
    setMySummaryHeaderCalc();
}, hotInstance);
```

Feel free to comment, I could improve my answer.